# Magento 1.9.x Product View > Show Last Order Date

Tags: date

I'd like to show the "date of the last order" on the view.phtml product page.

So far I've discovered "getCreatedAtStoreDate" from "design/template/sales/order/history.phtml.

But when I include these lines in view.phtml it results in the following error:
Call to a member function getCreatedAtStoreDate() on null in /.../view.phtml

Is there any simple way to show the date of the last purchase?
Maybe someone had this issue before. 
Thanks

Comment: you want to only for customer last order or common last order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a product is purchased, an Order Item is created. The way to go imho is to get the Order-Item-Collection, filter by `product_id` and sort by `created_at`. This should work (untested, though):

```
// only if product is not yet available
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');

// get newest order item of this product
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product->getId())->addFieldToSort('created_at', 'DESC')->addPageSize(1)->addCurPage(1);

if($collection->count()) {
    $item = $collection->getFirstItem();
    echo $item->getCreatedAt();
}
```

You should not use this kind of code in a template file, though. Make an own extension with an own Block-class and include this block in your layout.

Comment: this looks promising - gonna try.

Comment: Thanks! This worked; but I had to remove the following:

->addFieldToSort('created_at', 'DESC')->addPageSize(1)->addCurPage(1)

Comment: I've tried to add some information about the ordered customoptions.
So far the following does work; but it uses "Order ID" to sort out the result. Is there any way of using something like "Product ID->getLastOrder" instead?

Comment: If you remove "->addFieldToSort('created_at', 'DESC')", I am not sure it will work, because this filter sorts newest items first (I think, default is always by ID and ASC)

Answer (score 0):

To get last order,

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
       ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC')
       ->setPageSize(1);
       ->getFirstItem();
```

To get the last order by customer.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
```

Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Ajay & @simonthesorcerer - thanks.

I forgot to mention that it should be the "Last Orderdate for each product"

This date should be visible on each "Product Detail" page of the individual selected product.

Example:

Product-Id: 1; Last Date of Order: 04.04.2016

Product-Id: 2; Last Date of Order: 01.04.2016

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to add some information about the ordered customoptions. So far the following does work; but it uses "Order ID" to sort out the result. Is there any way of using something like "Product ID->getLastOrder" instead?

```
$incrementId = '100000108';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions(); 
    $customOptions = $options['options'];   
    if(!empty($customOptions))
    {
    foreach ($customOptions as $option)
    {       
        $optionTitle = $option['label'];
        $optionId = $option['option_id'];
        $optionType = $option['type'];
        $optionValue = $option['value'];
    }
    echo $optionValue;


    }
}
```

[Thanks @Mukesh](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-custom-option-value-from-order/)

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to make a column for the last ordered date of a product in Product grid, you can simply join `sales_flat_order_item` and use the code below in your select query

```
new Zend_Db_Expr("max(sales_flat_order_item.created_at)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should  work on view.phtml

```
$order_items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $_product->getId()))
    ->load();
    $order_items->getSelect()->order('created_at DESC');
    $order_items->getSelect()->limit(1);
    foreach ($order_items as $value) {
        echo $value->getCreatedAt();
    }
```